# Angular routing check if parameter is valid

Tags: angular

I have an **Angular 15** application with the following routes:

```
// app-routing.module
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ApplicationLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
      },
      {
        // other modules...
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '' // This redirects to the home page.
  }
];

// user-routing.module
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: UserComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'profile', component: UserProfileComponent },
          { path: 'settings', component: UserSettingsComponent },
          { path: 'notifications', component: UserNotificationsComponent },
          {
            // other routes...
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This configuration gives me the following routes:

- /user/**xxx**/profile
- /user/**xxx**/settings
- /user/**xxx**/settings/some-setting/...
- /user/**xxx**/**...**

### What am I trying to accomplish?

When navigating at any level of the **/user/:id** route, I want to display a **UserNotFoundComponent** if the provided User does not exist. Moreover, I want to be able to have access to the User object that was retrieved as part of the validation thorughtout the different child routes.
In essence, hitting **/user/invalid-id**, **/user/invalid-id/settings** or **/user/invalid-id/settings/setting-id** should render a **UserNotFoundComponent**, otherwise, the appropriate component configured for the route. And, if the user is valid, I want to have access to the User object as I'll be requiring further details for getting its settings, notifications, and other stuff.

#### Notes

I came across **Guards** and **Resolvers** but I'm not sure on what's the correct approach for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I also thought on having this route config:

```
// user-routing.module
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: UserComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'profile', component: UserProfileComponent }
          {
            // other routes...
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: UserNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

But I don't know from where to redirect to this route, and also, I would like to prevent users from navigating to **/user/404**.

---

#### Update 1

I created the following **Resolver** which returns either the User (if the user exists) or null (if it doesn't).

```
export function UserResolver(): ResolveFn<User | null> {
  return (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    const service = inject(UserService);
    const userId = parseInt(route.paramMap.get('id')!);
  
    return service.getUser(userId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          return of(null);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

I updated the **user-routing.module** as follows:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        resolve: {
          user: UserResolver()
        },
        component: UserComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'profile', component: UserProfileComponent },
          { path: 'settings', component: UserSettingsComponent },
          { path: 'notifications', component: UserNotificationsComponent },
          {
            // other routes...
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I updated **user.component.ts** as follows:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  public user?: User;
  
  constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}
  
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
      this.user = data['user'];
    });
  }
}
```

Finally, I updated **user.component.html** as follows:

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="user; else userNotFound"></router-outlet>
<ng-template #userNotFound>
  <user-not-found />
</ng-template>
```

This gives me the following behavior:

- When I hit any path under /user/:id, the Resolver gets triggered and gets the user from the backend.
- The UserComponent acts as a container of its child components, so, when initialized, I check whether the user is valid. If the user is valid, child components are loaded and displayed, otherwise, a message is displayed without having to navigate to some other route, as at the end, I don't want the URL to change nor having to define a route to which a user could manually navigate to.

Comment: Use `canActivate` and `resolve`. Guard to check if the user exists and resolver to supply all following routes with the User object.

Comment: @Akxe, I added **Update 1** section containing a description of the changes I've been playing around with. Does that sound like a good approach to you?

Answer (score 0):

As router URL **path match** works with **prefix** & **full** 
So, providing all exact url to open desired components.
Because by default the path match is **prefix**.

The ** is used at last index of routing so, from start the angular checks all routes if the route does not match to existing urls then this ** is called at the last.

**1. home/1  -> Login component 

2. home/1/catalog  -> Catalog component**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginViewComponent, HomeViewComponent, CatalogViewComponent,PageNotFoundComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: LoginViewComponent,
          },
          {
            path: ':id/catalog',
            pathMatch : "full",
            component: CatalogViewComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '**',
            component: PageNotFoundComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
         path: '**',
         component: PageNotFoundComponent,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
})
```